# vim syntax highlighting - highlight only 128 characters

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-syntax-highlighting

My vim editor highlight only 128 characters in string. 
In my .vimrc file I set syntax enable. When I change color scheme it's the same 128 characters highlighting.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your .vimrc. I suspect you have 'set synmaxcol=128'. Or maybe it's a weird default on your system. In vim do :help synmaxcol for more details.